# How java ThreadPool is designed to handle thread exception scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

I have a runnable which always throws some exception, say NullPointerException.
I am submitting 100000 of such runnable to the thread pool with ThreadPool size of 100.What will happen in this scenario . How does the thread pool handle the exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ExecutorService` provided thread pool any exception will not affect to worker thread .For an example if you are using callable then it will call on wrapper called `futureTask` which will handle if any exception thrown by your method.

Source code from Java API

```
Callable<V> c = callable;
            if (c != null && state == NEW) {
                V result;
                boolean ran;
                try {
                    result = c.call();
                    ran = true;
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    result = null;
                    ran = false;
                    setException(ex);
                }
                if (ran)
                    set(result);
            }
```